# Using Wordpress solely as a Backend - dealing with WP_SITEURL

Tags: rest-api, home-url

I've built a website in Angular that leverages Wordpress as a backend, specifically using its REST API. I am replacing an existing website, and my client does not intend to change the original hostname of their site. Initially I was hoping to publish Angular's static files to a CDN at their original hostname (myclient.com) and move their Wordpress to api.myclient.com. In this scenario my client would log in at api.myclient.com/login to manage their content there as well.

This is where I am starting to have some concern. I noticed a few issues, which are problematic, and I'm hoping someone might have a smart solution. The issues are as follows:

1. When I go to api.myclient.com/login and login, I am redirected to myclient.com/wp-admin, which is my CDN, so I cannot login.

Initially I found [this solution](https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/1965636), which outlines a way to allow my client to log into wp-admin at any domain. However, this presented a few other problems.

1. Jetpack is giving me warnings about entering safe mode because the Wordpress site has changed domains
2. If I create a new post, my RSS feed has links pointing to api.myclient.com rather than myclient.com
3. Publishing my website to social media links to api.myclient.com/post-slug rather than myclient.com/post-slug

Has anyone else run into this issue? My problems seem mainly related to jetpack, so if this is not the right forum for this kind of question please let me know!

Comment: Hi Bryan! Tough issue. Going completely headless is tough with WordPress. I have a feeling you'll have to handle each of these situations separately. For example, you can filter the content and search/replace the API domain with your live domain. Have you tried doing this for Jetpack or social sharing?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Mike! I am filtering out / modifying any api domains that come through the REST calls, but I was hoping I could still use some of jetpack's backend features such as the rss feed and social media posting. Even though I'm using Wordpress in a headless manner, do you think there are people out there who want to have a different /wp-admin domain than their front-end? I'd image they would run into the same issues.

Comment: I don't think you're alone, but I don't personally know of anyone doing this right now.